# How to automatically assign alfresco folders to have the 'Email alias' aspect?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'd like subfolders of an 'Inbound email' folder to automatically set an email alias matching their folder name.

I've applied the 'Email alias' aspect with a rule, now I'd like to know if there's any way to get the name of the folder I've just created within a javascript in the context of the rule that was just triggered by the folder creation.

In other words I need the created folder name so I can add it to the folder as the emailserver:alias property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

? You could just let the rule trigger a javascript and in that script you apply the aspect fill the metadata alias with the document.name .

Comment: "I'd like to know if there's any way to get the name of the folder I've just created"

Comment: Yes, do a rule on inbound folder, and fire a Javascript. set logger.log(document.name) and voila you'll have the name. Actually i'm telling exact the same as in my answer :), only now with more lines.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had a blind spot about a folder being a 'document'. Also in your first answer I missed the dot in 'the document.name' and just read it as 'the document name'

Comment: No Problem, if you use space which is more likely, it will take the parent of the content which is triggered.

Answer (score -1):

If you make that folder a custom type, then you can use `<mandatory-aspects>` block in your model, and when you create such folders, they'll always have the Email alias aspect.